# Sharepoint 2013 Webpart + Angular JS Internet explorer 9 compatibility

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I created a sharepoint 2013 webpart using AngularJS + Angular UI router. The app works fine on all browsers except IE9 and below. I don't care about IE8, but the app has to work at IE9.

I tried all possible solutions suggested by the ng-authors(change the doctype), and it only works on IE9 when the app is on a separate page. If it's within a webpart it doesn't work on IE9. I've wasted hours of my life to solve this issue, so any help will be appreciated.

Behavior of the app is shown on the screenshot below (the navigation bar doesn't havelinks anymore, it shows this cursor when hovered and nothing is shown within the ui-view):
http://s29.postimg.org/f8b1vzhk7/ie9.png

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using an iframe! The problem was that the doctype had to be html, and not the weird ones sharepoint produces. I changed the master templates but the problem still occured, so I solved it with the iframe and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can uncomment the imports of the file called "polyfills.ts" like the image. That work to me.

[Polyfills compatibility with Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gQ1.png)